# Is mutation of the Array returned by Object.keys() okay?

Tags: javascript

Is the return value of `Object.keys()` guaranteed to be a freshly allocated array, or should I copy it before destructively modifying/mutating it?

Comment: Let me google it for you. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: First, you can test this easily for yourself. Second, if mutating the content would alter other calls to `Object.keys()`, it would make `Object.keys()` nearly useless.

Comment: @Kinduser, if they link you provided says the answer, please help me understand where it said it, because I read that page prior to posting. They provide an implementation, but I don't think it's safe to assume that all JS implementations are identical to that implementation.

Comment: *The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties*

Comment: @Kinduser's documentation link also links directly to the relevant section of the spec. *"3. Let array be the result of creating a new Object as if by the expression **new Array(n)** where **Array** is the standard built-in constructor with that name."* Either way, if it's not safe to assume that a MDN polyfill is correct, why would it be any more safe to assume a StackOverflow answer is correct?

Comment: @squint Accurately as always.

Comment: "The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties" does not say whether it's freshly allocated or an internal, stateful storage that it would be a Bad Idea to modify.

Your link did not directly answer the question.

Comment: @user1106925 it's not safe to assume that because a random implementation returns a freshly allocated structure, that all implementations return a freshly allocated structure. All it takes is 1 implementation that caches results, and you have memory corruption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to copy it. `Object.keys` [creates a new array](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.14) every time. You can freely modify the returned array without affecting the original object.